# Javascript: Trim the length of string in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I would like to ask if it is possible to trim the length of multiple strings in an array in javascript.
The length of each string of my array is different, however I would like to trim the last 2 digit (meaning trimming "-2") for each of them.

```
var array = ["517577144-2","503222534-2","100003527692828-2","654703438-2","4205501-2"]
```

Cheers,
Karen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

map function:

```
array = array.map(function(d){return d.substr(0,d.length-2)});
```

or you can use slice method inside:

```
array = array.map(function(d){return d.slice(0,-2)});
```

Comment: @Moogs Good idea, updated the answer, string can be treated as an array:)

Answer (score 1):

another option is you can use map along  with  slice  function :

```
array = array.map(function(str){return str.slice(0,str.length-2)});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the 'map' function. This should do it for you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
var x;
for(x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
    array[x] = array[x].replace('-2', '');
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nf56dgev/)**

Comment: This, however, assumes that the '-2' substring only occurs at the ends of these strings.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the last character `-2` in the array.

```
   array = array.map(function(item) {
      return item.replace('-2', '');
    })
```

If you want to remove any character which is at the last not specifically `-2` then

```
 array = array.map(function(item) {
      return item.substr(0, item.length-2);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways to trim last two characters: `substr`, `substring`, `replace` or `slice` (cleanest solution).

```js
var array = ["517577144-2","503222534-2","100003527692828-2","654703438-2","4205501-2"];

// Using substr method

var trimmed = array.map(function(item) {
  return item.substr(0,item.length - 2);
});

log(trimmed);


// Using substring method

trimmed = array.map(function(item) {
  return item.substring(0,item.length - 2);
});

log(trimmed);


// Using regular expression in replace method

trimmed = array.map(function(item) {
  return item.replace(/.{2}$/,'');
});

log(trimmed);


// Using slice method

trimmed = array.map(function(item) {
  return item.slice(0,-2);
});

log(trimmed);


function log(array) {
   document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, null, 2) + '</pre>');
}
```

Instead of map you can always use a standard `for` loop too.

Answer (score 0):

Using open source project [jinqJs](http://www.jinqJs.com) it would simply be

```
var result = jinqJs().from(array).select(function(row){return row.slice(0, row.length-2);});
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tford/5xk2j4dq/)